# Click link after click another link

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a way to simulate a click on a link after having clicked another?

I have made this script:

```
$(".uno").click(function() {
    $(".due")[0].click();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ad3m8La/

When I click on "one" want "two" open the page as indicated.
My script does not work, and I do not understand why.

Comment: You can't reliably raise a click on an `a` element to redirect the page for obvious security reasons. If you need this behaviour you would need to get the `href` from the second link, then use `window.location.assign()` to redirect the user

Comment: Why would you need that? It doesn't make sense to me. Sounds like a XY problem, you should explain why you want this behaviour. And solution would be to delay click event using e.g a timeout   https://jsfiddle.net/5ad3m8La/3/   Reason must be because you cannot have more than one click event in same event stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your fiddle. Updated one https://jsfiddle.net/5ad3m8La/2/

Made few changes given below:

```
1. Added target="blank" in link.
2. Added http:// before google's link.
3. Wrapped your code in document.ready.
```

and it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
$('.due').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" class="uno">One</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="due">Two</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".uno" ).click(function() {
    $('.due').trigger("click");
});

$( ".due" ).click(function() { 
    var link= $(this).attr("href"); // you need to ger href and redirect to that link
    window.location.href = link;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".uno").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  location.href = $('.due').attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="uno">One</a>
<a href="google.it" class="due">Two</a>
```

This is not the same as emulating a click, but this way the behaviour is the same as clicking another linke (without special code attached to it)